# Can't change the datastore in Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, rest

I want to change the datastore, from oracle to postgres. I have installed the 2.8-SNAPSHOT version

I did perform a curl PUT request to change it

```
curl -u user:pass -X PUT  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/MYWorkspace/datastores/MyDataStore -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/xml" -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><dataStore>\t<name>MyDataStore</name>\t<type>PostGIS</type>\t<enabled>true</enabled>\t<workspace>\t  <name>MYWorkspace</name>\t</workspace>\t<connectionParameters>\t\t<host>myhost</host>\t\t<port>5432</port>\t\t<database>mydb</database>\t\t<user>postgres</user>\t\t<passwd>postgres</passwd>\t\t<schema>myschema</schema><dbtype>postgis</dbtype>\t\t</connectionParameters>\t<__default>false</__default></dataStore>
```

Pretty printed payload for easier reading:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataStore>
  <name>MyDataStore</name>
  <type>PostGIS</type>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <workspace>
    <name>MYWorkspace</name>
  </workspace>
  <connectionParameters>
    <host>myhost</host>
    <port>5432</port>
    <database>mydb</database>
    <user>postgres</user>
    <passwd>postgres</passwd>
    <schema>myschema</schema>
    <dbtype>postgis</dbtype>
  </connectionParameters>
  <__default>false</__default>
</dataStore>
```

The curl petition returned nothing; but I do see the changes in the datastore.xml file

But, when I enter into the datastore in geoserver, I get this error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this container for
rendering: [MarkupContainer [Component id = parametersPanel]] at
org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1765)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onBeforeRender(Form.java:2056) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:1531) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2292) at
org.apache.wicket.Page.prepareForRender(Page.java:1521) at
org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2329) at
org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:892) at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:261)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484) at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:156)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppDispatcher.doDispatch(AppDispatcher.java:67) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:654) at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
at
org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71) at
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppAuthFilter.doFilter(AppAuthFilter.java:111) at
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at
org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at
org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87) at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44) at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443) at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) at
org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:532) at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372) at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369) at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) at
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.getNamespaceByURI(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:678)
at
org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.getNamespaceByURI(CatalogImpl.java:1054)
at
org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.getNamespaceByURI(SecureCatalogImpl.java:360)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ian's valid points, I'll add that the XML does not seem like the one GeoServer would use/generate to describe a store, which looks as follows instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataStore>
  <name>gtttest</name>
  <type>PostGIS</type>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <workspace>
    <name>importer</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/importer.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </workspace>
  <connectionParameters>
    <entry key="schema">public</entry>
    <entry key="Evictor run periodicity">300</entry>
    <entry key="Max open prepared statements">50</entry>
    <entry key="encode functions">false</entry>
    <entry key="Batch insert size">1</entry>
    <entry key="preparedStatements">false</entry>
    <entry key="database">gttest</entry>
    <entry key="host">localhost</entry>
    <entry key="Loose bbox">true</entry>
    <entry key="Estimated extends">true</entry>
    <entry key="fetch size">1000</entry>
    <entry key="Expose primary keys">false</entry>
    <entry key="validate connections">true</entry>
    <entry key="Support on the fly geometry simplification">true</entry>
    <entry key="Connection timeout">20</entry>
    <entry key="create database">false</entry>
    <entry key="port">5432</entry>
    <entry key="passwd">pwd</entry>
    <entry key="min connections">1</entry>
    <entry key="dbtype">postgis</entry>
    <entry key="namespace">http://geoserver.org/importer</entry>
    <entry key="max connections">10</entry>
    <entry key="Evictor tests per run">3</entry>
    <entry key="Test while idle">true</entry>
    <entry key="user">user</entry>
    <entry key="Max connection idle time">300</entry>
  </connectionParameters>
  <__default>false</__default>
  <featureTypes>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/importer/datastores/gtttest/featuretypes.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </featureTypes>
</dataStore>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with don't use GeoServer 2.8-SNAPSHOT, the current stable version is 2.13.1. Unless you have an enormous number of these stores to change I would just use the GUI rather than REST or at least for the first one.

I suspect all sorts of things can go wrong switching a datastore type, most likely is that the table names have changed (Oracle and PostGIS have very different ideas as to table (and column) names).

Comment: the table names are the same, it only changed the convention (In oracle there is uppercase name, in postgres the opposite)

Comment: if you changed the case then they are not the same at all and I would expect this to fail.